# how to make sure env variable will not be displayed when ran a script in debug mode

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

```
[yesh]$ env | grep password
password=hello
```

-> tsts is my script which uses env variable password.

```
[yesh]$ grep password tsts

export DB_PWD="$password"
```

-> this is my script running in debug mode

```
[yesh]$ sh -x tsts

+ export DB_DD=yesh
+ DB_DD=yesh
+ export DB_USER=user
+ DB_USER=user
+ export DB_PWD=hello
+ DB_PWD=hello
+ echo 'sqlplus '\''user/hello@yesh'\'''

sqlplus 'user/hello@yesh'
```

What can i do so that password is not displayed while running script in debug mode??

Comment: Nothing. Even if the script is not run in debug mode, one can simply `cat` it and see it in the source code.

Comment: i mean what changes need to be done so that DB_PWD=hello is not displayed which is my env variable

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check and remember the current debug setting, i.e. whether
the option `-x` is in effect when the script is run. Then you need to
surround each statement that you don't want to get printed with `set +x`
to turn the option off and `set -x` to turn it back on when it was 
initially set. The variable `$-` contains the options that are in effect
when the script runs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export DB_DD=yesh
export DB_USER=user

# check and remember current setting of "-x":
if echo $- | grep -q x; then 
    is_debug=1
else
    is_debug=0
fi

[ $is_debug -eq 1 ] && set +x   # temporarily disable "-x"
export DB_PWD=hello             # won't be printed
[ $is_debug -eq 1 ] && set -x   # again enable "-x"

echo 'sqlplus '\''user/hello@yesh'\'''
exit 0;
```

**Output of `sh -x tsts`:**

```
+ export DB_DD=yesh
+ export DB_USER=user
+ echo x
+ grep -q x
+ is_debug=1
+ [ 1 -eq 1 ]
+ set +x
+ echo sqlplus 'user/hello@yesh'
sqlplus 'user/hello@yesh'
+ exit 0
```

But keep in mind that **this is pointless** because everyone who can
run your script can also look into it and see the password there.

Comment: tq for your efforts. its very important for me :) but what if i can't do any changes in script and can i add any command to sh -x so that password is not displayed??

Comment: @yeswanth No. Without changing the script it is not possible to suppress debugging output when it is run with `-x`.